# Android POST Json to API

Tags: android, json, android-studio, post, android-asynctask

I have a problem with sending Json from the application to the API. API = Spring + Hibernate. API will work because the sending Json POST program POSTMAN added to the database. Mobile application does not send JSON file. The transfer URL acts as the empty base form needed tables.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView txtStatus;
    LoginButton loginButton;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initializeControls();
        loginWithFB();

    }

    private void initializeControls(){
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        txtStatus = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtStatus);
        loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email", "user_birthday, user_photos"));

    }

    private void loginWithFB(){
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Log.e("Success", "Login");
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id, first_name, last_name ,email, gender, birthday");

                GraphRequest gr = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject json, GraphResponse response) {

                                String jsonResult = String.valueOf(json);
                                txtStatus.setText(jsonResult);

                                URL url = null;
                                try {
                                    url = new URL("http://pikmybeta.x3pg3pxqri.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/pikmy/user/create");
                                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                AsyncT asyncT = new AsyncT(jsonResult,url);
                                asyncT.execute();
                            }

                        });
                gr.setParameters(parameters);
                gr.executeAsync();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                txtStatus.setText("Cancelled");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                txtStatus.setText("Error " + error.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

.

```
public class AsyncT extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void> {

    String jsonResult;
    URL url;

    public AsyncT(String jsonResult, URL url) {
        this.jsonResult = jsonResult;
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            httpURLConnection.connect();

            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(jsonResult);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: It does not show error. In the table are part of "null"

Answer (score 0):

If you can do it with POSTMAN but not from the application try send it with volley library. It's really easy and helpful to work with and you can find lots of tutorials for that in the network. Here is the link to get started:

[Get Started: volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

[Tuturial for HTTP Requests](http://www.itsalif.info/content/android-volley-tutorial-http-get-post-put)